# numerically stable sparse Gaussian process regression (matrix inversion)

Tags: regression, covariance-matrix, gaussian-process, matrix-inverse

In sparse approximations of GP for large data set $(X,\mathbf{y})$ with $n$ samples, usually $m$ inducing points are chosen such that the true covariance matrix is approximated by $K_{nn}\to K_{nm}K_{mm}^{-1}K_{mn}$, where $K_{mn}=K_{nm}^T$ is the cross-covariance between inducing point and data points.
This results in a lower bound for the marginal likelihood (negative loss function) of (see Titsias 2009)
\begin{gather}
    F_V = \log\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2 I_{nn}+K_{nm}K_{mm}^{-1}K_{mn}) 
        - \frac{1}{2\sigma^2} Tr({K_{nn}-K_{nm}K_{mm}^{-1}K_{mn}})
\end{gather}
I have already coded this and the code is fast but it sometimes (50% actually!) fails.
Let $\Gamma=\sigma^2 I_{nn}+K_{nm}K_{mm}^{-1}K_{mn}$.
For evaluating this, we need to calculate (among other things)
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{y}^T \Gamma^{-1} \mathbf{y} + \log |\Gamma|
\end{equation}
I used Woodbury equations to convert $\Gamma^{-1} = \sigma^{-2}I_{nn} - \sigma^{-4} K_{nm} \Sigma_{mm}^{-1} K_{mn}$ where $\Sigma_{mm} = K_{mm} + \sigma^{-2} K_{mn}K_{nm}$. But apparently the Cholesky factorization (or inversion) of $\Sigma$ is not well conditioned.
Do you know any numerically stable and efficient algorithm to do this (invert $\Gamma$)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is some time ago that this question was asked, but I now also came across this problem and first implemented the inverse like you did. However, this is apparently numerical extremely unstable.

Following [Gaussian Processes for Machine Learning](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW8.pdf) I did a more stable implementation, where I first decompose the approximate co-variance matrix in a symmetric way as

$K_{nm}K_{mm}^{-1}K_{mn}=K_{nm}(L_{mm}L_{mm}^T)^{-1}K_{mn}=K_{nm}(L_{mm}^T)^{-1} L_{mm}^{-1}K_{mn}=\bar{K}_{nm}\bar{K}_{mn}$

where I used the Cholesky decomposition $K_{mm}=L_{mm}L_{mm}^T$ and inverted it to form the intermediate $\bar{K}_{nm}=L_{mm}^{-1}K_{mn}$, but you can also use an eigen decomposition to construct a similar intermediate.

Afterwards I could use the matrix inversion lemma to get

$(\hat{K}_{nm}\hat{K}_{mn}+\sigma^2I)^{-1}=\sigma^{-2}I-\sigma^{-2}\hat{K}_{nm}(\sigma^2I+\hat{K}_{mn}\hat{K}_{nm})^{-1}\hat{K}_{mn}$

which is at least for my cases numerical more stable. Still, for co-variance matrices with large condition number this still might be not so robust.

Comment: how is this O(Nm^2), when Knm x (mxm) x Kmn matrix multiplication exists?

Comment: The arithmetic complexity of a matrix multiplication of a (n x m) times (m x p) matrix is O(nmp). As you pointed out we have two matrix multiplication Knm x (mxm) x Kmn. These are two O(m^2n) operations. Are you fishing for that one should say it scales as O(2*m^2n) ?

Comment: fishing ? Do you first understand that this is O(nm^2) for the Knm x Kmm, O(n^2m) for Knm x Kmn?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Your are completely right. As you point out one will have O(n^2m) costs for the matrix multiplication. To arrive at lower cost one does not do this matrix multiplication, but does the multiplication with $\mathbf{y}$ to get the weights step wise. So first we mutliply K_mm with K_mn to K'_mn which scales as O(m^2n) and afterwards we multiply K'_mn with y_n which scales as O(mn) followed by a similar step to get the weights

Comment: I am not convinced of this answer, in fact previous researches clarify better using Eigenvectors/values instead of just mentioning painlessly the Woodbury formula

Comment: A stable version is implemented in [this GP library](https://github.com/wesselb/stheno). To be exact, investigate [this class](https://github.com/wesselb/stheno/blob/be4bb0c8e29550b73e4ce2db65ebb6bc727c32d7/stheno/model/observations.py#L168).